# How to call click event in Select2 after add a button to select2-drop and select2-no-results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I want to add a new  button to select2 drop even user can't get their result or not but after I append this button to after that i can't use jquery click.

```
$('.city').select2({
        formatNoMatches: function(term) {
            return "<a href='{{route('addNewIterms')}}' class='btn btn-info btn-sm' id='add'> Add New Item </a>";
        }
    });
Another solution
$('.select2-drop ').append("<a href='{{route('addNewIterms')}}' class='btn btn-info btn-sm' id='add'> Add New Item </a>");
```

But I can't call click event although I have try to jquery dom event like below

```
$(document).on('click','.select2-drop,.select2-drop#add', function(){
        console.log(this)
})
```

Comment: Your question is unclear!

Comment: when I used the Jquery select2 and I use Jquery append method both select formatNoMatches method to insert a button Add on select2 drop down but after that I  will use document.onclick to on this button but not work

Comment: Try to use punctuation. Otherwise it is really hard to understand you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `formatNoMatches` is removed from `Select2`.

You have to use the following syntax:

```js
$('#e1').select2({
  formatNoMatches: function(term) {            
     return "<button class='btn btn-info btn-sm' id='add'>Add a new item</button>";
  }, 
});

$('.select2-container').on('click', '#add', function() {
  alert('New Item Here!');
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.0.0/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/2.1.0/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<select multiple id="e1" style="width:300px">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
  <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
  <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sorry I have use select2 version 2

Comment: Maybe it not supported with version2 I have testing with this script more times still not work can you change to version 2?

Comment: @HengSopheak, check it now